# Is null string allowed for w, if "w ∈ {a, b}*"?

Tags: finite-automata, automata

If `L` is a language defined by :
`L = { awa | w ∈ {a, b}* }`,

is `aa` a string of the language `L`? (notice that `w` is being null string here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to you definition it seems L consists only of two words `aba` and `aaa`.

EDIT: after you have edited the question I can say `yes "aa" is a word of this language`
`w ∈ {a, b}*` means zero or more chars of this alphabet and thus w may have zero chars and be empty.

Comment: can't `w` be any combination of a's and b's ? something like : `abababa` ?

Comment: At least the notation I have seen would declare such language as:
`L = { awa | w ∈ {a, b}* } ` Note the star to indicate zero or more of.

Comment: Then yes `aa` is a word of the language

Comment: @abierto I am sorry but what you say definitely is not true. You may see I have posted a comment that made the OP change the question, my answer was correct before the edit and my explanation of the comment **before** the OP change the question is again the only thing I used in my answer. I can guarantee I have not used any information in your answer in any way. Of course you are free to believe me or not

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem can be restated as this.

```
L= a(a|b)*a
```

Which translates into intuition as "Strings that begin with and end with 'a'". So naturally, 'aa' is a valid string.

I hope this answers your question.